# Audio playback through headphone jack working only on right side

Tags: 18.04, sound, audio-jack

I have been using Ubuntu bionic beaver for a few days and it worked fine until now. It still works on the windows partition. But now when I plug headphones to the jack it only plays from the right side. The sound is also somewhat diminished. I have tried fixing it by alsamixer and pulse audio. It plays nothing when testing audio from settings for left side. Bluetooth working fine.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a desktop, and if so do you have two audio jacks (one on the front and one on the back)? In my case the back one gives me full left and right audio while the front jack only has right audio.

Comment: No. I'm using a laptop and it has only one.

Comment: And it works on Windows.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of alsamixer and PulseAudio Volume Control

Comment: It was a hardware problem. Thank you for your response.